# Sending commands from Raspberry PI to arduino and the other way around in C++

Tags: c++, boost, arduino

I'm trying to do a project where I want to send some commands to my arduino UNO from my rpi. I have them connected via USB. I asked around my circle of friends and they said to use `boost:asio` library along with the `streambuffer` and  `async_write` and  `async_read` function.

They suggested those because I also want to send data from my arduino.

I realize that first I have to create an IO service because and this is the code I use to create it:

```
boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
boost::asio::serial_port serial(ioservice, "/dev/ttyACM0");

serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port::flow_control::none));
serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::parity(boost::asio::serial_port::parity::none));
serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port::stop_bits::one));  serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port::character_size(boost::asio::serial_port::character_size(8)));
```

The stream buffer is then created by doing:

```
boost::asio::streambuf b;
```

For better understanding of the problem, the commands I want to send to arduino from rpi are strings, for example string="g 50"  and the information I want to send from arduino to rpi are 2 vectors(vect_1 and vect_2) each one with 3 floats. If possible I want to pass these 2 vectores at the same time.

How can I send data to my arduino or my rpi using this streambuf b? And how can I put data in b? Can I send these 3 vectors simultaneously through the stream or is it impossible? To read them is it just the  `async_read` or something else is needed?

Comment: Using asynchronous I/O means having some experience with multithreaded, event driven development.  So the aswer depends on what you are trying to do, and how you will use the data.  It may be easier and faster to do synchronous i/o, still using the boost::asio library,.  What does the rest of the application look like?  Are you simply harvesting data? Do you have a graphical interface?  Are you moving data to the web though a socket?

Comment: From the arduino I'm simply harvesting data (those 2 vectors) From the rpi I simply want to send commands to the arduino. I didn't think of that possibility cause all my friends told me about async_read, but yeah I could just simply use read to make it syncronous. Later I will make an interface but now I'm not trying to do it

Comment: So you just want a loop with repeated commands / responses ?

Comment: Yes, And first I want to be able to receive the data arduino sends